# Load a default shell from vim

Tags: vim

When I open up a terminal my default shell looks something like this:

```
XX-DEV-IM-MM:Ingest david$
```

However, when I do `:term` in vim I get something like this for my shell (looks like a root bash shell):

```
bash-3.2$
```

Is there a way to use my default system shell rather than this one that doesn't load my `.bash_profile` and such?

Comment: Is the $SHELL environment variable set correctly? Also, some systems load bash_profile/bashrc differently based on whether or not it’s interactive/login, so check if it’s login/not etc

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for pointing this out. No, I don't believe it's set properly. How would I set this properly, or is there a link to docs where I can learn about possible ways to set it?

Comment: your shell should set `SHELL` in the environment; when `:term` is run without arguments, it defaults to `$SHELL`. Fire up a terminal and try `printenv SHELL`. If that comes back with your actual shell, then you probably just a have bashrc/_profile issue